# How to receive and extract json in HTTP GET request body

Tags: java, api, rest

I'm am pretty new to Java and I'm trying to create an API which handles `GET` requests.
The basic code works but without being able to receive any parameters in the body. Most of this code is based on code I've found. What do I need to change if I want to handle json data in the request body?

The working API without parameters:

```
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;

public class API {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        String responseText = calculation.data();
        HttpServer server = HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(8080), 0);
        server.createContext("/api", (exchange -> {

            if ("GET".equals(exchange.getRequestMethod())) {

                exchange.sendResponseHeaders(200, responseText.getBytes().length);
                OutputStream output = exchange.getResponseBody();
                output.write(responseText.getBytes());
                output.flush();
            } else {
                exchange.sendResponseHeaders(405, -1);
            }
            exchange.close();
        }));

        server.setExecutor(null);
        server.start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With a proper implementation a GET request method won't accept a body. You can use a handler for a request method that can accept a body (PUT, POST, etc.) i.e. `else if ("POST".equals(exchange.getRequestMethod())) {` or pass parameters via URL.

Comment: Ok the POST method works but how do I get the body ? If i try to access `exchange.getResponseBody();` I see this: `sun.net.httpserver.PlaceholderOutputStream@13eeb5a3`